# How long should Google App Engine HRD migration take?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a super-trivial application on GAE that I want to upgrade to HRD so that I can rewrite it in Go. So far the migration has been running for 12 hours, and is hung at "Copy..."

Given that my app does not save any data to any datastore, should it be taking this long?

Comment: Also experiencing this problem. Haalp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was my app hadn't saved any data. Saving a single value resolved it immediately.

Answer (score 2):

No. You likely have encountered a bug and if you post to the HRD migration group then a google employee can reset your migration and let you try again.

Here's the HRD migration google group where you can contact an admin:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gae-hrd-migration-testing

I hope this can help you.